# Настроить две логические подсети в одной физической

Tags: windows, сервер, маршрутизация, подсети

Наконец появилась и возможность и необходимость разобраться с маршрутизацией и сетями. В один свитч воткнуты машины с ип-шниками (допустим) `192.168.0.1\24` и `192.168.1.1\24`, и в тот же свитч воткнут вин сервер. У сервера два алиаса на одну сетевуху, допустим: 192.168.0.10/24 и 192.168.1.10/24. У машин шлюз по умолчанию - этот вин сервер. И что я только не пробовал с таблицей на сервере - не направляет он трафик из одной сети в другую. Помогите, чем можете. Какая еще информация нужна? Собственно, причина нашлась. Я не указал на машине во второй подсети шлюз по умолчанию.

Comment: Если по серьезному, то дела такие:>`Здание 1 ( Кучка машин + вин сервер = Свитч 1)-----оптоволокно------Здание 2 ( Свитч 2 = Кучка машин + вин сервер)`И таких зданий будет четыре. И все физически - в одной сети. Как такое дело лучше настроить? Есть проблема с разбиранием серверов - они на гарантии, мы не можем воткнуть в них оптические сетевухи.

Comment: Значит так и стройте. Ваши свитчи поддерживают VLAN? Сколько всего машин будет в сети?

Comment: Свитчи, как я понял, не настраиваются вообще. Либо я чего-то не знаю. Жаль не записал модели. Машин в каждой сети по разному. 10-30 на здание. Мы-то так и строим, но, хотелось-бы, разделить это на подсети. Как я понимаю, без физического разделения или VLAN - широковещательные все равно будут ходить по всем зданиям, не смотря на подсети?

Comment: Нет, если разделить на подсети, то не будут. Они ограничатся только своими сетями. В данном случае я бы предложил разбить для начала разбить один диапазон на 4 части. Т.е. вы берете, например, 192.168.0.0/24 и впихиваете все компьютеры в него (1 здание: 1-64, 2 здание 65-128... и т.д.) В случае чего не сложно будет потом и переконфигурировать все для маршрутизации, выбрав /26 маску.

Answer (score 1):

Советую так никогда не делать, если свитч не имеет [VLAN](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLAN) (иначе лишний широковещательный трафик из другой сети будет лететь во все остальные, а VLAN ограничит его в своем широковещательном домене).

Если сделать 192.168.0.10/23, то никакая маршрутизация не нужна. Машины, естественно, тоже необходимо переконфигурировать на 192.168.0.0/23 и выдать айпишники из диапазона 192.168.0-1.1(0)-254(5). Но шлюзом для всех машин все равно останется 192.168.0.10. В данном случае с обыкновенным свитчем будет работать.

Если необходимо все же маршрутизацию, тогда вопрос:

А между компами в одной сети пакетики бегают?

Что касается таблицы, она не требует дополнительной настройки, ибо пакеты идущие через шлюз в другую сеть будут автоматически переброшены в нее (другую сеть) потому, что в таблице маршрутизации уже имеется запись о двух интерфейсах.

**UPD**

В [данной](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315236) записи от Майкрософт говорится, о том, что необходимо сделать дабы включить маршрутизацию в Windows (именно на сервере, на главном маршрутизаторе, на обычных машинах толку от данной операции никакого).

**UPD2**

Так как человек молчит, могу предположить, что решение все же нашлось.

Comment: В том и дело, что трафик не маршрутизируется. Подсети работают вполне нормально. Все машины в подсети пингуются друг-другом, включая сервер. Сервер, тоже пингует любую машину в любой подсети, имея ип-шники из обеих подсетей. Но tracert глохнет на сервере. Из обеих подсетей.

Comment: 1. А таблицу маршрутизации можете привести?2. Необходимые службы запущены?3. Фаервол на блокирует трафик?

Comment: 1. http://zalil.ru/31609250 (в коммент не влазит)2. А какие службы? Маршрутизация? Без нее не работает гуй по настройке маршрутов, так-что да.3. Фаервола нет.

Comment: На мой взгляд все нормально. Чувствую, что где-то маленькая ошибочка и поэтому все не работает.

Comment: Должны же быть какие-то средства диагностики. Есть же причина, по которой он не направляет пакет дальше. Знаете такие софтины?

Comment: Не сработало. К вин серверу, насколько я знаю, эта настройка вообще не относится, на рабочей машине уже было включено.

Comment: А как насчет VPN?

Comment: Я про то что можно раздавать всем общую сеть, а через VPN разделить на подсети. Или так нельзя?

Comment: Ну по моему это хороший вариант, если свичи не управляемые и разделить на подсети зачем то приспичило.

Comment: Вариант то хороший, только с точки зрения затрат и юзабилити для клиента не всегда приемлемый.

Comment: С точки зрения затрат согласен, но если вспомнить об автоматизации - не исчезнет ли неудобство для клиента?

Comment: А как вы хотите автоматизировать подключение к VPN? Ну и к тому же я уже сказал, что для соединения двух сетей, идея, скажем мягко, ни о чем. Зачем делать виртуальную сеть поверх и так работающей физической, которую можно замечательно разбить на подсети, без хитростей VPN. Ведь по сути вам на шлюзе все равно делать то же самое в итоге да и к тому же ВПН поднимать.